# out of process rendering

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to implement out of process rendering for my application (like what chrome does). I have the ipc (interprocess communication) all set up and working however it just deadlocks when trying to init a new form on the other process.

I have started the process with inherit handles as true is there any thing else i need to do?

I happy to provide sample code if needed.

Edit: it deadlocks in window api calls. Runs fine when in the same process

Comment: You will have to provide the relevant code. Try using the debugger to find the exact places in the code where it deadlocks, and then post them.

Comment: Ok, which APIs? What are the parameters?

Comment: Multi-threading and multi-process are different in that with threads they share the same memory space and file handles, and in Windows they share process-level resources. Make sure your settings are correct, as you are probably waiting for some event which is only single-process scope and so your other process cannot set this.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to couple two threads if they own windows with any kind of relationship.

The effective result of this is, your IPC calls cannot block when waiting for a reply - your IPC reads always need to use [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx) so that you can process window messages from the other process/thread while waiting for the IPC message indicating completion.

---

What you do is replace your current call to WaitForMultipleObjects with MSGWaitForMultipleObjects. When it returns, you check the return value. If nCount is the number of IPC handles you are waiting to be signalled:

```
// Pump messages while waiting on 0 or more handles.
for(;;)
{
   while(PeekMessage(&msg,0,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
   {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }

   DWORD ret = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(nCount,pHandles,FALSE,dwTimeout,QS_ALLEVENTS);
   if(ret >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && ret < (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + nCount))
   {
     // one of the handles was signalled.
     return ret;
   }
   else if(ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + nCount)
   { 
     // The wait was aborted because there is at least one message, 
     // go back to pumping messages
     continue;
   }
   else
   {
     // test for WAIT_OBJECT_ABANDONED_0, WAIT_TIMEOUT etc. as appropriate
   }
}
```

Comment: i use WaitForMultipleObjects for the ipc atm. How would i change it to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects?

Comment: I think i get it. So in my ipc read thread i would also run a message pump and i would peek or read to no messages left then use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects and once thats done peek and read again?